# Загрузка проекта на github

Tags: git, github

Есть готовый проект написанный в VS 2015. При создании проекта система контроля версий не была выбрана. Нужно залить его на github. Перепробовал кучу способов ничего не получается.

Comment: в VS 2015 есть Team Explorer. в нем можно подлючиться к github.

Comment: А поподробней? Аккаунт на github я создал, в студии подключился к нему. А как проект залить?

Comment: в Team Explorer вверху есть иконки. под ними: выпадающий список. в нем - sync.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Скачайте [gitextensions](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gitextensions/)
- Установите
- Откройте программу и создайте репоризторий. Для этого нажмите по
  кнопке слева `Create new repository`. Укажите путь к исходникам,
  нажмите `Сreate`.
- После создания репозитория, гит проиндексирует файлы внутри,
  нажмите `commit`(кнопка посередине). Выберите файлы(слева) и нажмите
  `Stage``Stage All`.(Там же можно настроить .gitignore выбрав файлы и
  нажав add to .gitignore).
- Нажмите на панели меню кнопку `Repoitory`->`RemoteReposotories`. В
  открывшемся окошке укажите название репозитория, адрес(можно
  скопировать с репозитория с гитхаба), и желательно добавить ключ,
  после нажмите `Save Changes` и закройте окошко.
- Нажмите `Push`(рядом с кнопкой commit)